# Set textView text to a remote config default value from layout xml file

Tags: xml, firebase, android-layout, firebase-remote-config

I have a use case where I need to store the default values stored in the remote config xml directly in a textview of my layout xml file without using `textView.setText()` method

I know that I can simply get the value in java code and then set it to a textview with setText() method. But is there a way of getting the default remote config value and storing in textview from layout XML like such `android:text="@string/txt"`?

Here is my remote config default xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<defaultsMap>
    <entry>
        <key>main_activation_cost</key>
        <value>1000</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>discount_activation_cost</key>
        <value>500</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>total_referral_count</key>
        <value>5</value>
    </entry>
</defaultsMap>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to simply specify a Remote Config parameter in Android XML layouts.  You will have to write code to fetch the parameter, then populate the views with that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes there is a way to bind strings from XML

Declare your XML like below

<layout xmlns...>

<data>

    <import type="packagename.constants.IConfigConstants" /> //your remote config 
    constants file

        <variable
            name="firebaseConfig"
            type="com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig" />

</data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"                                 
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"                        
    android:text="@{firebaseConfig.getInstance().getString(IConfigConstants.STRING_KEY)}" />
```